# Differential amplifier and different ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, grounding, virtual-ground

I am designing a circuit to measure the voltage across the output of buck converter. With different ground for the buck converter and the micro controller, with respect to which ground will the ADC measure?

[image: Different ground]

For the circuit shown above, the ADC will measure the output with respect to which ground? Isn't the input to the ADC floating?

If the above circuit is not a good design practice or if it doesn't work, will the below circuit work provided the output voltage of the first op amp is within the voltage range of the second op amp?

[image: Different op amps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grounds are floating.

There are two problems with the designs:

- The design will be susceptible to any kind of noise, because the GND2 is floating with respect to GND1. EMI could cause GND2 to be a higher voltage (and the second board will function like an antenna)
- There is no return path for the current flowing from the board with GND1 to the board with GND2 (in the diagrams in the OP). This means the only return path for current will be through the air and the current will be very very small, not enough to overcome the input bias current needed almost all amplifiers.

You'll need some kind of connection between grounds. If you want to isolate the grounds between boards use an isolation amplifier such as the [adum3190](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum3190.html). These amplifiers use chopping to pass the analog signal through an isolation transformer, then reconstruct it. (you still need to provide a ground from one board to the next, but the grounds are not tied together on the same board). If your trying to save on wiring, there is simply no way to pass an analog signal between boards without a return path for the current (it's like trying to get current from a battery without connecting a wire to the other terminal).

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum3190.html

> will the below circuit work provided the output voltage of the first
> op amp is within the voltage range of the second op amp?

There will be no reference for the ADC to base the voltage because GND1 is floating, it will pick up a reading but it would be similar to connecting a wire to the ADC and air.

> For the circuit shown above, the ADC will measure the output with
> respect to which ground? Isn't the input to the ADC floating?

The ADC is always referenced to it's ground GND2 (many ADC's have built in voltage references that are referenced to ground).

> will the below circuit work provided the output voltage of the first
> op amp is within the voltage range of the second op amp?

Probably not, it will depend on the voltage of GND2 and if GND2 is only connected by air, then no current will flow between boards and there will be no way for a voltage to be determined by the buffer amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

1. In these topologies you would ground R3 to your microcontroller ground GND2, not GND1 if you want the amplifier output to be the voltage across R2 referenced to GND2.
2. The TLO81 doesn't have a common mode input range that includes ground.  Select another amplifier or use split supplies.
3. 100 ohms is kind of low, 1K is probably the minimum you would want to use.  You probably want to use much more if you want your two grounds isolated.
4. How far apart can your grounds drift?  If there's no limit you can't guarantee being within the common mode or input range specs on your op-amp.
5. The common mode rejection will be dependent on the matching of your resistors around the op-amp.  If I remember right 1% resistors get you about 48dB worst case (or somewhere around that).  So that should be factored in as an error term along with offset, etc.
6. I don't see a need for an additional buffer after the diff amp.
7. For better accuracy and isolation between the two circuits you could consider an instrumentation amp, or even an isolation amplifier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The opamp that I had in mind is LM324 and the resistor values are just for an example. Simply connecting the resistor R3 to GND2 should work then?

Comment: Yes, with the caveats above, though note you will be connecting your two grounds together through R3 and R5.  Also, the LM324 can only swing to within 20mV of ground so if you have to be accurate down to 0V you might still want a negative supply for the amp.

Comment: But I wish to avoid connecting the two grounds together. What should I do then. Would an instrumentation amplifier suffice because they have a separate reference pin?

Comment: How much isolation do you need? An instrumentation amp is better, but doesn't provide as much isolation as an iso amp like this:https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso224.pdf?ts=1595867829910&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FISO224%253FkeyMatch%253DISO224%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN

Comment: I don't necessarily need isolation. Take a look at this https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/common-problems-when-designing-amplifier-circuits.html "FIGURE 9". Can i connect the 100k of the op amp buffer to the GND2?

Comment: You can connect the reference input directly to GND2 if you want, or you could buffer it.  Watch all the common-mode input and output swings if you use an instrumentation amp.  If your two grounds have no relationship to each other then they could float apart enough to damage your amplifiers so consider adding some impedance or a bidirectional TVS between the two.  (This ISO amp is good up to 5kV RMS for 1 minute if you absolutely want to keep the grounds isolated).

Comment: If you don't need isolation, Why don't you connect GND1 and GND 2. As I see it, You are connecting it to 30V DC supply(So not AC mains). So you don't actually need isolation. So connecting GND 1 and 2 will solve your problem. Why are you avoiding it? I'm curious

Comment: @varun Say you have two buck converters and you wish to connect them in series. Connecting the grounds together will short one buck converter.

Answer (score 0):

But that's not the case here is it?. The Opamp is referenced to GND1, so its output will also be referred to GND1. The ADC won't be able to read the value.

I do see one solution though. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I see that you are measuring the voltage across R2, and the gain is 1. The voltage across R2 is 3.3V. So the output of the opamp would be 3.3V. If you can increase V2 to 5V, and power the opamp with V2, then the ADC will read 3.3V. This way you would be able to sense up to 4V without saturation, that's sensing rage of 0-36V. If you need to increase the range, increase V2 accordingly. That circuit will work. You won't have to connect the grounds together.