# Different Ground reference

Tags: schematics, ground, grounding, texas-instruments, virtual-ground

I plan on making my own BMS for a 12S battery pack, and I found TI's TIDA BMS board and decided to use it as a reference to gain some understanding on how to develop safety circuit for the board. While studying [the schematic](https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidm788/tidm788.pdf?ts=1691052565808) of the board, at a point they are using different reference for something I don't properly.

[image]

As you can see, the D46 and D45 Schottky Diodes are connected to PACK- pin, while the Zener(s) are connected to GND. Also, what is the purpose of shorting PACK- with PACK+ pins? Shouldn't the PACK- pin connected to the GND?

I went through this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512581/differential-amplifier-and-different-ground), but I don't think the purpose of different reference is the same in this case. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The pack- is not shorted to pack+.

And the ground reference GND for the circuit is the battery cell negative terminal.

And pack- is connected to GND, quite well actually, via 1 milliohm shunt resistor for current measurement.

Comment: So then what is the need of D45 and D46? Why they have written PACK- while the Zener(s) have GND?